# number of orders of certain type before every order

Tags: sql, hana

A customer has orders and each order of either a type 1 or type 2. I would like to Count how many times each type has occcured **before** each order.

For example for one customer:

```
customer | orders| Type
---------+-------------
customerA| Order1| 1
customerA| Order2| 1
CustomerA| Order3| 2
customerA| Order1| 1
customerA| Order2| 2
customerA| Order3| 2
CustomerA| Order1| 1
customerA| Order2| 2
```

Required results:

```
    customer | orders| Type| Nr_typ1| Nr_typ2
    ---------+-------+-----+--------+-------
    customerA| Order1| 1   |   0    |   0
    customerA| Order2| 1   |   1    |   0
    CustomerA| Order3| 2   |   2    |   0
    customerA| Order1| 1   |   2    |   1
    customerA| Order2| 2   |   3    |   1
    customerA| Order3| 2   |   3    |   2
    CustomerA| Order1| 1   |   3    |   3
    customerA| Order2| 2   |   4    |   3
```

what i was trying was:

```
select t.customer, t.orders, t.type, sum(t.type1), sum(t.type2) from
(select customer, orders, type,
case type = 1 then 1 else 0 end as type1, 
case type = 2 then 1 else 0 end as type2
from table customer_orders) t group by customer, orders, type
```

Any suggestions would be higgly appreciated! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that HANA supports [windowed aggregates](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.00/en-US/20a353327519101495dfd0a87060a0d3.html). The following script was tested on SQL Server but I believe the same query should work on HANA:

```
declare @t table(customer varchar(20) not null, orders varchar(10) not null, Type int not null)
insert into @t(customer,orders,Type) values
('customerA','Order1',1),
('customerA','Order2',1),
('CustomerA','Order3',2),
('customerA','Order1',1),
('customerA','Order2',2),
('customerA','Order3',2),
('CustomerA','Order1',1),
('customerA','Order2',2)

select
    *,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Type=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER
    (PARTITION BY customer
    ORDER BY orders
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) -
    CASE WHEN Type=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as TotalType1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Type=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER
    (PARTITION BY customer
    ORDER BY orders
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) -
    CASE WHEN Type=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as TotalType1
from @t
```

Results:

```
customer             orders     Type        TotalType1  TotalType1
-------------------- ---------- ----------- ----------- -----------
customerA            Order1     1           0           0
customerA            Order1     1           1           0
CustomerA            Order1     1           2           0
customerA            Order2     2           3           0
customerA            Order2     2           3           1
customerA            Order2     1           3           2
CustomerA            Order3     2           4           2
customerA            Order3     2           4           3
```

Hopefully the definitions of the windows are reasonably easy to tease apart - nobody ever accused SQL of being terse.

(I'm not getting the exact results requested in the question but that's because the sample data set doesn't contain an adequate column to place in the `ORDER BY` clause, such that "before" is well defined. I'm currently using `orders` but that's not unique)

Comment: Damien `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` I have no idea that this exists. Can you please refer me reference Manual corresponding to it? Thanks!

Comment: @Sai - already linked from the answer, in first sentence. Unfortunately, it's quite a long page but if you search for `UNBOUNDED` that should get you to approximately the right part of the document.

Comment: Thank you very much. its really interesting. Hav learned something very new today.

Answer (score 0):

You can use with `WHILE` loop in SQL like below. (#order is my order table, you change it to your actual table)

Create table to store result:

```
CREATE TABLE #res 
    (customer varchar(100),
    orders varchar(100),
    [type] int,
    Nr_typ1 int,
    Nr_typ2 int)
```

Declare some variables and cursor for `WHILE` loop:

```
DECLARE @Customer varchar(100), @Order varchar(100), @Type int, @nr_type1 int = 0, @nr_type2 int = 0

DECLARE order_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT customer, orders, [type]
FROM #orders
```

Loop over your table:

```
OPEN order_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM order_cursor INTO  @Customer, @Order, @Type

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #res
    VALUES(@Customer, @Order, @Type, @nr_type1, @nr_type2)    

    IF @Type = 1
        SET @nr_type1 = @nr_type1 + 1
    ELSE 
        SET @nr_type2 = @nr_type2 + 1

    FETCH NEXT FROM order_cursor INTO  @Customer, @Order, @Type
END
```

Print result:

```
SELECT * FROM #res
```

Close cursor after use:

```
CLOSE order_cursor
DEALLOCATE order_cursor
GO
```

Drop your result table if you no longer need:

```
DROP TABLE #res
```